# how to send xml file to amazon mws using php

Tags: xml, curl, amazon-mws

I am trying to send xml file to amazon mws marketplace along with I am sending query parameters like marketplace id, accesskey etc.
below is the code snippet, I am testing this snippet locally I am getting the following error,

**Error: necessary data rewind wasn't possible
Error Code : 401**

```
    $file   =   "C:\\ListOrdersResponse.xml";
    $fopen  =   fopen($file,"r");

    $urluse =   "https://mws.amazonservices.in";


    $postArray  =   array();
    $postArray['AWSAccessKeyId']    =   'MYKEY';
    $postArray['Action']            =   'SubmitFeed';
    $postArray['FeedType']          =   '_POST_PRODUCT_PRICING_DATA_';
    $postArray['SellerId']          =   'MYSELLERID';
    $postArray['SignatureMethod']   =   'HmacSHA256';
    $postArray['SignatureVersion']  =   2;
    $postArray['Timestamp']         =   gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s.\\0\\0\\0\\Z", time());
    $postArray['Version']           =   '2011-10-01';

    $url_string     =   http_build_query($postArray);
    //signature
    $signature      =   $postArray['Action'] . $postArray['Timestamp'];
    $actualSig      =   base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha256", $signature, $postArray['AWSAccessKeyId'], true));

    $postArray['Signature']         =   $actualSig;

    $httpHeader     =   array();
    $httpHeader[]   =   'Transfer-Encoding: chunked';
    $httpHeader[]   =   'Content-Type: text/xml';
    $httpHeader[]   =   'Content-MD5: ' . base64_encode(md5_file($file, true));
    $httpHeader[]   =   'Expect:';
    $httpHeader[]   =   'Accept:';

    $curl_options   =   array(
        CURLOPT_UPLOAD  =>  true,
        CURLOPT_INFILE  =>  $fopen,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  =>  true,
        //CURLOPT_PUT       =>  TRUE,
        //CURLOPT_POST  =>  true,
        //CURLOPT_PORT  =>  443,
        //CURLOPT_SSLVERSION    =>  3,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST  =>  false,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  =>  false,
        //CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION    =>  1,
        //CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS =>  CURLPROTO_HTTPS,
        CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT =>  TRUE,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER  =>  $httpHeader,
        //CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST =>  'POST',
        //CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS    =>  $url_string,
        CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH    =>  CURLAUTH_ANY,
        CURLOPT_USERPWD => "snapdeal:snapdeal",
        CURLOPT_VERBOSE =>  true,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST   =>  'PUT',
        CURLOPT_HEADER  =>  true
    );

    $ch =   curl_init($urluse.'/?'.$url_string);
    curl_setopt_array($ch,$curl_options);
    $response   =   curl_exec($ch);


    /*$fp   =   fopen("C:/result.xml","wb");
    fwrite($fp,$response);
    fclose($fp);*/
    if (curl_errno($ch)) { 
        print "Error: " . curl_error($ch);
        print_r(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE)); 
    } else { 
        // Show me the result 
curl_close($ch);
    }
```

Can any one help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The "necessary data rewind wasn't possible" error message seems to be related to using CURLOPT_INFILE in conjunction with http redirections (http codes 301 or 302, see [here](http://evertpot.com/curl-redirect-requestbody/))

The way out is either not to use streams (e.g. use POSTFIELDS instead of INFILE) or to provide an interface so that curl can rewind the stream via [SEEKFUNCTION](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTSEEKFUNCTION) if it encounters a redirect.

The following snippet is from code that is actively being used to send XML data via MWS (admittedly not to Amazon India, if that makes any difference). It does not use streams and as such has a larger memory overhead:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://'.$AmazonMWShost.'/'.$apiurl.'?'.FieldsToURL($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: text/xml","Content-MD5: ".$contentmd5,"x-amazon-user-agent: MyScriptName/1.0"));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, what do I need to send through fields. I am sending action, seller id etc through fields. Is it correct.

Comment: @NagarajuVadlamudi The `$data` in above snippet is a string that contains the XML to be sent, $fields is an array similar to your $postArray.